# ¿Una laguna en el apartado «¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta a mi pregunta?» de la ayuda?

Tags: discusión, bug, estado-completado, centro-de-ayuda

El apartado de la ayuda: **[¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)**  dice lo siguiente:

> Lo primero que debes hacer después de leer una respuesta que alguien
> <s>dejo</s> a tu pregunta es votar. Vota a favor de esas respuestas que son
> útiles y bien investigadas y vota en contra de esas respuestas que no
> lo son. Otros usuarios también <s>votaran</s> por tus respuestas en otras
> preguntas.

En [la versión en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), ese apartado tiene ***al menos*** un enlace donde dice [*vota a favor*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) (enlace a la página del privilegio "votar a favor" en SOes)  y [*vota en contra*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) (enlace a la página del privilegio "votar negativo" en SOes).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La versión en castellano, por el contrario, no tiene **ni siquiera** un enlace.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿No se podría mejorar de alguna manera, y no sólo poniendo un enlace, sino explicando brevemente, ahí mismo, cómo se vota a favor o en contra?**

Es un enlace al que muchos de nosotros hacemos referencia cuando respondemos a preguntas de usuarios que inician en el sitio y creo que sería útil enriquecer ese contenido con una explicación breve, e incluyendo por supuesto los enlaces.

> **PD**: Y de paso:
>
> - no dejamos más **dejo**, pues debería ser **dej     ó**.
> - sigamos votando en el futuro.

Comment: y por ende, "votarán" y no "votaran".

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo, pero en lugar de ampliar el texto, porqué no poner enlaces igual que en la original? Tenemos [votar a favor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) y [votar negativo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) igual que en el sitio en ingles traducidos.

Comment: @Pikoh, creo que con los enlaces y una media línea explicando cómo se vota a favor o en contra no vendría mal. Quedaría mucho mejor que en inglés, tomando en cuenta que así matamos tres pájaros de un tiro.

Comment: Me parece bien. Todo lo que sea aclarar las cosas a usuarios nuevos me parece perfecto, siempre estaré a favor :)

Comment: Corregido en [Traduzcamos las páginas y enlaces del “Centro de Ayuda”](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3321/83)