# Traduzcamos las páginas y enlaces del "Centro de Ayuda" y de "Privilegios"

Tags: bug, estado-completado, traducciones, centro-de-ayuda

En el [Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) hay algunos artículos sin traducir:

- <s>[What is a locked post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/locked-posts)</s> traducido
- <s>[What should a tag wiki excerpt contain?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts)</s> traducido
- <s>[I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)</s> traducido

Así como algunos que no tienen los enlaces a páginas en castellano:

- [¿Por qué ya no se aceptan preguntas desde mi cuenta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)

Y otros tienen algún que otro error:

- <s>[El usuario "Comunidad" ha eliminado mi pregunta. ¿Que paso?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/roomba)</s> corregido
- <s>[¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)</s> corregido

Y en la página de privilegios falta por traducir:

- <s>[Reduce Ads](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads)</s> traducido

g3rv4 amablemente creó un proyecto en GitHub para que si le proporcionamos la traducción, él la suba a la página:

> se aceptan PRs [acá](https://github.com/g3rv4/help-pages). Si me dan una mano traduciendo los puedo actualizar  <sub>[sacado del chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43123796#43123796)</sub>

El proceso se detalla [en esta respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4467/11272).

¡Animaos pues a traducir! Se trata de editar las respuestas que pongo a continuación. A continuación yo mismo haré una Pull Request para subir la traducción al GitHub y que g3rv4 lo suba a la web.

Comment: Creo que debe quitarse [meta-tag:estado-completado] por haberse agregado un nuevo elemento por hacer.

Comment: @Rubén puedes reportar y pedirlo a un moderador.

Comment: @Rubén de hecho el tema es que esta manera de proceder (traducciones comunales) parece que no gustó demasiado, pero yo encantado de seguir procediendo así.

Comment: Mas que pedirlo a un moderador habría que comentarlo con @g3rv4. En cuanto a que no gustó demasiado, pienso que muchos no se han enterado de este hilo.

Comment: @Rubén me refiero a que la gente (moderador incluido) optó por hacer PR directamente, cosa legítima sin duda. Por ello aflojé mi petición porque pareció que la gente prefería hacerlo de esa forma. Lo mismo es porque no se enteraron de este hilo, no sé. Sea como fuere, lo importante es que se traduzcan y la gente le dé pasadas para mejorarlo

Answer (score 3):

[estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado)

[What is a locked post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/locked-posts)

Enlaces internos que están en inglés:

- [Who is the Community user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user)
- [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work)
- https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/03/04/the-great-edit-wars/
- [A guide to moderating comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237978/a-guide-to-moderating-comments)

## Traducción al castellano

Una publicación que está "bloqueada" no puede ser modificada de ninguna manera. El bloqueo impide...

- votar en la publicación (incluyendo votar para cerrar/reabrir en las preguntas)
- editar
- comentar
- responder (para preguntas)
- reportar (aunque los reportes del tipo "es necesario la  intervención de un moderador" sí que están permitidos, excepto en el caso de los bloqueos con Significado Histórico - véase a continuación)

### ¿Quién puede bloquear una publicación?

[Los moderadores del sitio](/help/site-moderators) pueden aplicar tipos específicos de bloqueos a las preguntas y respuestas.

Además, [el sistema en sí](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user) <sub>en inglés</sub> bloqueará las publicaciones en ciertas situaciones:

- si la publicación es eliminada a través de un  [reporte  como "spam" o "abusivo"](/help/privileges/flag-posts).
- si la publicación es migrada a otro sitio.
- si la publicación se migró *al* sitio actual, y luego es [rechazada](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work) <sub>en inglés</sub>.
- si una pregunta se fusionó con otra, las respuestas se moverán y la pregunta de origen se bloqueará.

### ¿Cuánto tiempo permanecen bloqueadas las publicaciones?

Esto depende de por qué estaba bloqueada.

- Cuando un moderador bloquea una publicación debe seleccionar el tiempo que el bloqueo debe permanecer en su lugar. Las opciones son: 1 hora, 1 día, 1 semana o permanente. Al final de este período, el sistema la desbloqueará automáticamente.
- Cuando el sistema bloquea una publicación, permanece bloqueada indefinidamente; solo un moderador puede desbloquearla.

Un moderador puede desbloquear manualmente una publicación bloqueada en cualquier momento si lo considera necesario.

### ¿Cuándo se debe bloquear una publicación?

Como regla general, se deben usar bloqueos *temporales* cuando las modificaciones a una publicación estén causando problemas serios en el sitio. Por ejemplo:

- [Guerras de ediciones](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/03/04/the-great-edit-wars/) <sub>en inglés</sub>.
- Disputas extendidas en los comentarios (véase también: [una guía para moderar los comentarios](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237978/a-guide-to-moderating-comments) <sub>en inglés</sub>).
- Una publicación polémica que está en discusión en el sitio Meta.

Los bloqueos *permanentes* casi nunca deberían usarse, con la excepción de los impuestos por el sistema en sí. Hay dos excepciones:

1. Una pregunta extremadamente popular que ahora se considera inapropiada para el sitio puede estar bloqueada por *Significado Histórico*: esto altera la apariencia de la pregunta, también bloquea automáticamente todas las *respuestas* y deshabilita los reportes por completo. Este bloqueo debe reservarse para los casos en que de otro modo se eliminaría un artefacto cultural preciado; **no** lo debe usarse para ningún otro propósito.
2. Una "wiki" es una pregunta cuyas respuestas [pueden ser editadas por usuarios de baja reputación](/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki), atribuidas a múltiples autores, y que no otorgan reputación al autor original. En ocasiones, son útiles en casos donde la información *debe* ser compilada por múltiples autores (por ejemplo, una lista de recursos o documentación para el sitio en sí); en estos casos, bloquear la pregunta evita que se cierre y evita que se agreguen más respuestas.

#### Véase también:

- [¿Qué es una publicación bloqueada?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1994/qu%C3%A9-es-una-publicaci%C3%B3n-bloqueada)
- [¿Qué es un bloqueo de importancia histórica y para qué se usa?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1996/qu%C3%A9-es-un-bloqueo-de-importancia-hist%C3%B3rica-y-para-qu%C3%A9-se-usa)
- [Opciones Avanzadas de Búsqueda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/searching)

---

## Texto original en inglés

Una publicación que está "bloqueada" no puede ser modificada de ninguna manera. El bloqueo impide...

- ...voting on the post (including close/reopen votes for questions)
- ...editing
- ...commenting
- ...answering (for questions)
- ...flagging (though "in need of moderator intervention" flags are still allowed, except in the case of Historical Significance locks - see below)

### Who can lock a post?

[Site moderators](/help/site-moderators) can apply specific types of locks to questions and answers.

Also, [the system itself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user) will lock posts in certain situations:

- if the post is deleted via ["spam" or "abusive" flags](/help/privileges/flag-posts).
- if the post is migrated to another site.
- if the post was migrated *to* the current site, and then [rejected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work).
- if a question was merged into another question, the answers will be moved and the source question will be locked.

### How long do posts stay locked?

This depends on why it was locked to begin with.

- When a moderator locks a post they're required to select how long the lock should remain in place. The options are: 1 hour, 1 day, 1 week, permanent. At the end of this time, the system will automatically unlock it.
- When the system locks a post it stays locked indefinitely - only a moderator can unlock it.

A moderator can manually unlock a locked post at any time if they deem it necessary.

### When should a post be locked?

As a general rule, *temporary* locks should be used whenever modifications to a post are causing serious problems on the site. For example:

- [Edit wars](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/03/04/the-great-edit-wars/)
- Extended bickering in comments (but see: [a guide to moderating comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237978/a-guide-to-moderating-comments))
- A controversial post that is under discussion on meta

*Permanent* locks should almost never be used, with the exception of those imposed by the system itself. There are two exceptions:

1. An extremely popular question which is now considered inappropriate for the site may be locked for "Historical Significance": this alters the appearance of the question, automatically locks all *answers* as well, and disables flagging completely. This lock should be reserved for cases where a cherished cultural artifact would otherwise be deleted; **do not** use it for any other purpose.
2. A "wiki" is a question whose answers [can be edited by low-reputation users](/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki), attributed to multiple authors, and do not grant reputation to the original author. They're occasionally useful in cases where information *must* be compiled by multiple authors (for example, a list of resources or documentation for the site itself); in these cases, locking the question both prevents it from being closed and prevents further answers from being added.

#### See also:

- [What is a "locked" post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post) en Meta Stack Exchange
- [What is a historical lock, and what is it used for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for) on Meta Stack Exchange
- [Advanced search options](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching)

Comment: Agregué la traducción a esta wiki, también ya hice mi pull request correspondiente, cualquier mejora o cambio se agradece.

Comment: @iuninefrendor qué bueno y veloz :) Optaría por hacer el pull request después de que pasen unos días, para así dar tiempo a que distintas personas le den una pasada. ¡Gracias por el trabajo! Dejo enlace de la PR: https://github.com/g3rv4/help-pages/pull/2

Comment: si existe alguna otra mejora, agrego otro PR y lo subo, no hay problema, además podría ser mucho el tiempo hasta que distintas personas le den una vista y puedan mejorarlo o inclusive ninguna persona lo haga.

Comment: @iuninefrendor como se ha visto en la otra respuesta, en los dos-tres primeros días es cuando hay muchos ojos y disposición ([ejemplo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3275/83)). De ahí que crea mejor esperar ese mínimo tiempo antes de sugerir una PR. Sugiero que esperes ese tiempo, ya me encargo yo de la siguiente PR.

Answer (score 3):

[estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado)

[What should a tag wiki excerpt contain?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts)

Enlaces internos que están en inglés:

- [wiki de etiqueta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms/)

## Traducción al castellano

Las etiquetas son una buena guía de los temas permitidos en tu sitio (e, implícitamente, los que no lo están). Por ello, las dos primeras páginas de etiquetas deberían tener al menos excelentes extractos de etiquetas wiki. Si además tienen una [wiki de etiqueta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms/) <sub>en inglés</sub> muy buena y completa, tanto mejor; pero bueno, hay que gatear antes de poder caminar. Por ello, es recomendable centrarse en un extracto de ~500 caracteres: es un texto que aparece en varios lugares del sitio, incluidos los mouseover de etiqueta.

### Pautas para escribir extractos de etiqueta útiles

1. **El extracto es el texto de presentación de una etiqueta.** Solo tienes ~500 caracteres de texto sin formato para el extracto, ¡así que no te sientas obligado a cubrirlo todo en él! Guárdalo para la wiki de etiqueta, donde puedes utilizar markdown y hasta 30.000 caracteres. El extracto debe definir la naturaleza compartida de las preguntas que contienen esta etiqueta, explicada en unas pocas oraciones cortas.
2. **Evita definir conceptos genéricos en una etiqueta**, a menos que sea altamente especializada. La etiqueta "correo electrónico", por ejemplo, *no* necesita explicar qué es un correo electrónico. Podemos asumir con seguridad que la mayoría de los usuarios de Internet saben qué es un correo electrónico; no aporta ningún valor dar una explicación trillada sobre qué es correo electrónico.
3. **Concéntrate en lo que significa una etiqueta para *tu* comunidad.** Para "correo electrónico" en [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), menciona los aspectos del servidor de correo electrónico, incluidos POP3, SMTP, IMAP y el software del servidor. Para "correo electrónico" en [Super User](https://superuser.com/), menciona los clientes de correo electrónico de escritorio y excluye explícitamente el correo web, ya que sería más apropiado para el sitio [Web Applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com).
4. **Proporciona una guía básica sobre cuándo usar la etiqueta.** En otras palabras, *¿Qué tipo de preguntas debería tener esta etiqueta?* Las etiquetas solo existen como formas de organizar preguntas, de modo que si no proporcionamos la orientación adecuada sobre qué preguntas *necesitan* esta etiqueta, no se etiquetarán en absoluto, haciendo que el extracto de la etiqueta sea discutible. Piensa en ello como una propuesta: en una sala llena de etiquetas que gritan "¡seleccióname!", ¿qué convencería a quien pregunta para que seleccione tu etiqueta?
5. **Algunas etiquetas son de conocimiento común.** La mayoría de las etiquetas requieren un poco de explicación en el extracto, incluso si solo son 3 o 4 palabras. Pero si la etiqueta es de conocimiento común, es decir, si *te acercaras a una persona al azar en la calle y le dijeras el nombre de la etiqueta*, ellos sabrían de qué estaba hablando, entonces no te molestes en explicar la etiqueta en absoluto. Indica en el extracto cuál es el uso que la comunidad le está dando.

---

## Texto original en inglés

Tags are the de-facto map of allowed (and implicitly disallowed by omission) topics on your site. That’s why the first two pages of tags should have excellent tag wiki excerpts at a minimum. If they have great, complete [tag wikis](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms/), that’s even better, but you have to crawl before you can walk. Focusing on the ~500 character excerpt is a simple way to get started — and that text is surfaced in a bunch of places on the site, including tag mouseovers.

### Guidelines for writing useful tag excerpts

1. **The excerpt is the elevator pitch for the tag.** You only have ~500 plain text characters for the excerpt, so don’t feel obligated to cover everything in it! Save that for the 30,000+ character Markdown tag wiki. The excerpt should define the shared quality of questions containing this tag — boiled down to a few short sentences.
2. **Avoid generically defining the concept behind a tag**, unless it is highly specialized. The “email” tag, for example, does *not* need to explain what email is. I think we can safely assume most internet users know what email is; there’s no value in a boilerplate explanation of email to anyone.
3. **Concentrate on what a tag means to *your* community.** For “email” on Server Fault, mention the server aspects of email including POP3, SMTP, IMAP, and server software. For “email” on Super User, mention desktop email clients and explicitly exclude webmail, as that would be more appropriate for http://webapps.stackexchange.com.
4. **Provide basic guidance on when to use the tag.** In other words, *what kinds of questions should have this tag?* Tags only exist as ways of organizing questions, so if we don’t provide proper guidance on which questions *need* this tag, they won’t get tagged at all, rendering the tag excerpt moot. Think of it as a sales pitch: in a room full of tags screaming “pick me!”, what would convince a question asker to select your tag?
5. **Some tags are common knowledge.** Most tags require a bit of explanation in the excerpt, even if it’s only 3 or 4 words. But if the tag is common knowledge — that is, if you *walked up to any random person on the street and said the tag word to them*, and they would know what you were talking about — then don’t bother explaining the tag at all. Stick to usage of the tag within your community in the excerpt.

Comment: aqui tuve muchas dudas en el primer y en el ultimo parrafo, espero puedan dar una mejor propuesta antes de dar un PR.

Comment: @iuninefrendor sí, lo de _elevator pitch_ es muy complicado de traducir ([en Spanish.SE lo hemos discutido alguna vez](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/4208/1674)). Opté por utilizar _texto de presentación_, que creo que se entiende bien.

Comment: algunas pequeñas modificaciones en la gramática ;)

Comment: @iuninefrendor gracias por las correcciones, se me pasó alguna errata. Sobre _para el extracto, ¡Así que_, es incorrecto: tras una coma nunca puede ir una mayúscula. El resto bien, dale si quieres a la PR :)

Answer (score 3):

[estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado)

Traducción de **[¿Por qué ya no se aceptan preguntas desde mi cuenta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)**

Enlaces internos que están en inglés:

- [realizar preguntas es un privilegio, no un derecho](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/04/asking-better-questions/), entada del blog de Jeff Atwood
- [Writing the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) por Jon Skeet
- [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), de Meta Stack Exchange

## El texto ya estaba en castellano (3 enlaces modificados; faltan 2)

En Stack Exchange, [realizar preguntas es un privilegio, no un derecho](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/04/asking-better-questions/) <sub>en inglés</sub>. Si un usuario no puede demostrar, después de realizar un número razonable de preguntas, que sus contribuciones están haciendo del sitio un lugar mejor (o, al menos, no lo están empeorando), entonces se le bloqueará de formular preguntas antes que demuestre su capacidad de contribuir positivamente.

Stack Exchange tiene filtros automáticos para prohibir preguntas realizadas desde cuentas que han contribuido con muchas preguntas de baja calidad en el pasado. Estos filtros ayudan a mantener alta la calidad de nuestros sitios. La fórmula exacta de las prohibiciones no ha sido revelada, pero solo se aplica a usuarios que tengan un número significativo de preguntas con bastantes votos negativos, sin votos, o publicaciones eliminadas. Una o dos publicaciones malas no van a causar que se te prohíba usar el sitio.

Los usuarios que tienen prohibido realizar preguntas ven el siguiente mensaje de error al tratar de publicar una nueva:

> Ya no aceptamos preguntas de esta cuenta. Consulta el [Centro de ayuda](/help/question-bans) para obtener más información.

Las prohibiciones sobre preguntas no afectan otros privilegios como comentar o votar y no hay ninguna indicación al resto de la comunidad de que un usuario en particular haya sido bloqueado.

### ¿Cómo puedo salir de la prohibición de preguntar?

La prohibición será levantada automáticamente por el sistema cuando determine que tus contribuciones positivas superan aquellas preguntas que fueron percibidas negativamente.

#### Stack Exchange no puede levantar manualmente prohibiciones de preguntar

La única manera de acabar con la prohibición es contribuir positivamente al sitio, las prohibiciones automáticas nunca expiran o vencen. **Comienza por arreglar tus [preguntas existentes](/users/current?tab=questions)**, *no*  publiques la misma pregunta nuevamente. Se espera que todas las preguntas sean útiles también para visitantes futuros, así que esfuérzate en escribir con gramática y ortografía apropiadas, con formato agradable a la vista e incluyendo todo el detalle posible sobre tu problema y qué has intentado previamente. Leer tu pregunta en voz alta para ti mismo puede ayudarte a entender cómo le sonará a otros. Aquí tienes algunas recomendaciones adicionales para escribir preguntas buenas y útiles:

- [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](/help/how-to-ask) de nuestro Centro de Ayuda.
- [Writing the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) por Jon Skeet <sub>en inglés</sub>.
- [Cómo hacer preguntas de manera inteligente](https://sindominio.net/ayuda/preguntas-inteligentes.html) por Eric S. Raymond, traducido por Jose M. Fernández.
- [Obteniendo respuestas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3274/obteniendo-respuestas).

Para aprender sobre cómo dar formato a tu publicación en StackExchange:

- Lee nuestra [ayuda de Markdown](/editing-help).
- Lee [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) <sub>en inglés</sub>.
- Experimenta tú mismo en [Pruebas de formato (Sandbox)](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1706/pruebas-de-formato-sandbox).

Si ves un mensaje similar al tratar de publicar una respuesta, por favor revisa nuestras guías sobre [qué hacer sobre las prohibiciones de respuestas](/helpcenter/answer-bans).

Comment: En este caso en particular, no mantuve el "original" porque me pareció innecesario (ya estaba traducido, solamente es modificar los enlaces)

Comment: @Mariano ¡gracias! Casualmente, estaba haciendo una revisión profunda del redactado, pues veo que [la versión actual en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) tiene un encabezado nuevo.

Comment: modificala como que fuera tuya :-)) Sólo aclaré lo que había hecho, pero esto se arma entre todos... Si querés agregar el "nuevo" original abajo, también me parece bien

Comment: @Mariano :) ¿Qué te parece que deberíamos hacer con las publicaciones aún en inglés? ¿Sería pertinente traducir en Meta páginas como la de [_Getting Answers_](http://www.mikeash.com/getting_answers.html) de Mike Ash?

Comment: la verdad no lo sé. Opciones que se me ocurren: (1) dejarlo en inglés (2) una publicación en meta incompleta, como un *placeholder*, donde ahora tenga una respuesta sólo con el link a la publicación en inglés, pero que se pueda mejorar en futuro (3) una traducción del artículo... Creo que cualquiera de las opciones son válidas, y que van a depender de lo que quieran contribuir los usuarios.

Comment: @Mariano me gusta la opción (2), pero no sé si quedaría demasiado bonito. Para (3) me gustaría que la gente se animara a hacerlo, que si no siempre somos los mismos proponiendo.

Comment: A mí también. Ahora veo de publicar algo del estilo de (2). Si en el futuro la comunidad lo termina convirtiendo en (3), genial también... Si queda o no bonito, veremos, en principio creo que le gana a tener "*Getting Answers*" como enlace en inglés en nuestra ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

[estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado)

Mejora de la traducción de [El usuario "Comunidad" ha eliminado mi pregunta. ¿Que paso?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/roomba)

El título necesita tildes: **El usuario "Comunidad" ha eliminado mi pregunta. ¿Qué pasó?**

Enlaces internos que están en inglés:

- [El usuario Comunidad](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19738)

---

[El usuario Comunidad](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19738) borrará automáticamente preguntas viejas o abandonadas en las siguientes circunstancias:

**Si la pregunta tiene más de `30` días de antiguedad y...**

- puntuación de −1 o menor
- no tiene ninguna respuesta
- no está bloqueada

**... o ...**

- la pregunta fue cerrada y migrada hacia otro sitio de la red Stack Exchange.

... será borrada automáticamente. A este tipo de preguntas se las llama "muertas" (`RemoveDeadQuestions`, o `RemoveMigrationStubs` en caso de migración)

**Si la pregunta tiene más de `365` dias de antigüedad y...**

- puntuación de 0, **o** puntuación de 1 y la cuenta del propietario está eliminada.
- no tiene ninguna respuesta
- no está bloqueada
- tiene un número de vistas <= 1,5 veces la edad de pregunta (en días).
- tiene uno o ningún comentario.

... será borrada automáticamente. A este tipo de preguntas se las llama "abandonadas" (`RemoveAbandonedQuestions`).

Estas reglas se ejecutan una vez a la semana en todos los sitios.

**Si la pregunta fue cerrada hace más de `9` días y ...**

- no fue cerrada como duplicada
- puntuación de 0 o menos
- no está bloqueada
- no tiene respuestas con puntuación > 0
- no tiene respuesta aceptada
- no tiene votos de reapertura pendiendtes
- no ha sido editada en los últimos `9` días

... será borradas automáticamente. A este tipo de preguntas se las llama "cerradas y abandonadas" (`RemoveAbandonedClosed`).

Esta regla se ejecuta una al día en todos los sitios.

Véase también la publicación oficial ["¿Cómo funciona la eliminación de publicaciones? ¿Por qué podría eliminarse una publicación y qué implica? ¿Cuál es el criterio para eliminar?"](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1033/83).

Answer (score 1):

[estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado)

[¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Se ha cambiado HTML por markdown, así como recogido lo dicho en [¿Una laguna en el apartado «¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta a mi pregunta?» de la ayuda?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2905/83) y actualizado respecto la información en SO [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers):

---

Determina si la respuesta es útil y entonces...

1. **Vótala**. [Vota a favor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) las respuestas que sean útiles y bien investigadas y [vota en contra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) las respuestas que no lo sean. Otros usuarios también votarán las respuestas a tu pregunta.
2. **Acéptala**. Como autor de la pregunta, dispones de una opción adicional: [aceptar la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) que pienses que es la mejor solución a tu problema.

**[Cómo aceptar una respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427/)**:

- Escoge la respuesta que pienses que tiene la mejor solución a tu problema.
- Marca la respuesta como aceptada: haz clic en la marca al lado de la respuesta (debajo del contador de puntos a favor o en contra); al hacer clic, cambiará de gris a verde.
- Puedes cambiar la respuesta aceptada o eliminar su estado como aceptada en cualquier momento.

Aceptar una respuesta no es obligatorio; no te sientas presionado a aceptar la primera respuesta que recibas. Espera hasta que recibas la respuesta que conteste tu pregunta de la mejor manera.

**Por favor *no* añadas un comentario a tu pregunta diciendo “Gracias”**. Los comentarios fueron diseñados para pedir clarificaciones, dejar críticas constructivas o añadir información adicional; no para socializar.  Si quieres decir “gracias”, vota a favor o acepta la respuesta de ese usuario.  También puedes compartir tu agradecimiento dando una gran respuesta a una pregunta de otra persona.

Answer (score 1):

[Reduce Ads](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads)

[estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado)

Nota: también debe traducirse el texto a la derecha:

> Some ads are now automatically disabled

En algo así como:

> Algunos anuncios se inhabilitan automáticamente

[estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado)

---

## Traducción al castellano

#### ¿En qué consiste ver menos anuncios?

Como cortesía hacia nuestros usuarios más ávidos, automáticamente les desactivamos ciertos anuncios cuando alcanzan este nivel de reputación.

#### ¿Cómo sé que está funcionando?

Al obtener este privilegio, los dos anuncios centrales son suprimidos en las páginas de la preguntas cuando navegues con la sesión iniciada.

[image: zonas de anuncios]

Las áreas en rojo corresponden a la publicidad central. Las áreas grises son la publicidad de la barra lateral, que permanecerán visibles.

#### ¿Qué hay acerca de los sitios Meta?

Los sitios Meta no tienen publicidad, así que este privilegio no es relevante allí.

#### Pero, ¿y si yo todavía deseo ver esa publicidad?

Si tú decides que realmente quieres ver la publicidad porque esta es útil o interesante para *ti*, entonces puedes desactivar este privilegio en tu perfil. Haz clic en "Editar Perfil y Configuración", luego haz clic en "Preferencias". Habrá una opción para volver a habilitar esta publicidad, si lo deseas:

[image: inhabilitar/rehabilitar publicidad]

Queremos enfatizar que solo debes volver a habilitar la publicidad si *tú* quieres verla, no porque estés intentando apoyarnos financieramente. De hecho, no nos hace ningún bien mostrarte publicidad de productos que no deseas comprar o contratar. Así que toma la decisión que sea mejor para ti: eso será lo mejor para nosotros también.

---

## Versión original en inglés

#### What is reduced advertisements?

As a courtesy to our avid users, we automatically disable some ads when they reach this reputation level.

#### How do I know it's working?

After you achieve this privilege, the two "leaderboard" style ads will be automatically suppressed from question pages when you are logged in.

[image: ad zones]

The areas in red are the leaderboard ads. The areas in gray are the sidebar ads, which will remain visible.

#### What about Meta sites?

Meta sites have no advertisements so this privilege is not relevant for them.

#### But what if I still want to see those ads?

If you decide that you really like seeing banner ads because they're useful or interesting to *you*, then you can disable this privilege in your profile. Click on "Edit Profile & Settings", then click on "Preferences". There will be an option for re-enabling these ads, should you wish:

[image]

We want to emphasize that you should only re-enable banner ads if *you* want to see them, not because you're trying to support us financially. In fact, it doesn't really do us any good to show you ads for products that you don't want to engage with. So make the decision that's best for you, and that's the one that's best for us too.

Comment: Hice algunas modificaciones menores sobre esta respuesta. Asumo que lo mejor es que 1 sola persona maneje el estado de cada PR.

Comment: ¡Gracias @Mariano! También tenía pendiente revisarlo, la versión actual es la que [propuso Rubén en GitHub](https://github.com/g3rv4/help-pages/pull/12) hoy mismo :) Démosle alguna pasada más y en unos días hacemos el PR.

Comment: Además, quería ver tu opinión sobre: `los dos anuncios publicitarios del tipo "tabla de clasificación"`... No sé si hay una traducción para "*leaderboard*", pero me parece que no se entiende así. ¿Será mejor reemplazarlo por algo como `los dos anuncios centrales`?

Comment: @Mariano _leaderboard_ en este sitio lo hemos ido traduciendo como [_usuarios principales_](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/discusi%C3%B3n/topusers), pero en este caso claramente es un caso diferente. Creo que se entiende mucho mejor lo que propones de _anuncios centrales_, es muy descriptivo.

Comment: Claro, no se refiere a *usuarios principales*, sino a *leaderboard style*, es decir, habla del formato que tienen los anuncios. Quizás haya algún término técnico, pero modifico con "centrales" y si a alguien se le ocurre algo mejor, que lo cambie.

Comment: Gracias @Mariano, ya hice la PR después de dar unos días para que se revisara entre todos.

Answer (score 1):

[¿Qué es la reputación? ¿Cómo se gana (y se pierde)?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Modificación del texto `es.SOcom` → `SOes`,
[propuesta](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43951873#43951873)
por [Jorgesys](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/95/jorgesys).

[estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado)

---

#### La reputación es algo totalmente opcional

Las tres acciones más importantes en Stack Overflow son [preguntar](/help/how-to-ask), [contestar](/help/how-to-answer) y [editar](/help/editing). ¡Y para ninguna de ellas es necesaria ningún tipo de reputación!

*Por favor, intenta sentirte cómodo con estas tres acciones antes de ir más allá en tu participación en otras áreas del sitio.*

#### Así pues, ¿qué es la reputación?

La reputación es una medida aproximada de cuánto confía en ti la comunidad; se gana convenciendo a tus iguales (los otros miembros de [SOes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)) de que sabes de lo que estás hablando.

A medida que ganes más reputación ganes, obtendrás más [privilegios](/privileges) y  podrás acceder a más herramientas del sitio. Cuando llegues al mayor nivel de privilegios tendrás acceso a [muchas de las herramientas](/help/privileges/moderator-tools) disponibles para los [moderadores del sitio](/help/site-moderators). Esto tiene una intención claro: nosotros no hacemos funcionar el sitio, ¡la comunidad es la que lo hace!

#### ¿Cómo gano reputación?

La principal manera de ganar reputación es haciendo buenas preguntas y dando respuestas útiles. Los votos que recibas sobre estas publicaciones te harán ganar (o, a veces, perder) reputación. Ten en cuenta que los votos sobre las publicaciones marcadas como "Wiki de la comunidad" no generan ninguna reputación.

Puedes ganar hasta un máximo de 200 puntos diarios mediante cualquier combinación de las actividades descritas mas abajo. [Las recompensas](/helpcenter/bounty), [las respuestas aceptadas](/helpcenter/accepted-answer) y [el bonus de asociación](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/cross-site-account-associations/) no se aplican al limite diario de reputación.

**¿Cuándo gano reputación?**

- tu pregunta es votada a favor: +5
- tu respuesta es votada a favor: +10
- tu respuesta es marcada como "aceptada": +15 (y +2 para quien "acepta" la respuesta)
- una edición sugerida es aceptada: +2 (hasta +1000 en total por usuario)
- una recompensa es otorgada manualmente a tu respuesta: + el total del monto ofrecido como recompensa
- una recompensa otorgada automáticamente a tu respuesta: + la mitad del monto ofrecido como recompensa (mas detalles de como funcionan las recompensas).
- bonus de asociación: +100 en cada sitio (solo se otorga una vez por sitio)

Si eres un usuario experimentado de la red Stack Exchange con 200 o más puntos de reputación en al menos uno de los sitios, recibirás un bono de +100 puntos de reputación que te servirá para eliminar las restricciones comunes a usuarios nuevos.

**¿Cuándo pierdo reputación?**

- tu pregunta es votada en contra: -2
- tu respuesta es votada en contra: -2
- tú votas en contra una respuesta de otro usuario: -1
- tú ofreces una recompensa sobre una pregunta: - el total del monto ofrecido como recompensa
- una publicación que has hecho recibe 6 reportes de spam u ofensivo: -100

Todos los usuarios comienzan con un punto de reputación y su reputación nunca podrá ser menor que 1. Aceptar tu respuesta a una pregunta que tú mismo hiciste no otorga ninguna reputación. Si un usuario revierte un voto, la reputación otorgada (ganada o perdida) también se revierte. Si un voto es revertido por considerarse un voto fraudulento, también la reputación es revertida (ya sea ganada o perdida).

#### Pero quiero votar y comentar en cosas eliminadas

Todo esto son actividades secundarias en Stack Overlow; empieza familiarizándote con preguntar, contestar y editar, para así tener una mejor idea de cómo es la cultura del sitio y ver cómo tu propio trabajo pasa a ser parte del sitio. A medida que lo hagas, de forma natural irás ganando el privilegio de hacer más cosas si te apetece. ¡[Mira tu perfil](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/current) de vez en cuando para ver cómo de cerca estás de ganar tu siguiente privilegio!

Comment: Este es otro de los casos donde el documento original incluye información adicional → https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation. Por ejemplo, el bloque _Reputation is entirely optional_.

Comment: @fedorqui no es lógico que eso suceda? Por supuesto que esperaría que los artículos de ayuda vayan evolucionando con el tiempo... Y perfectamente se le puede agregar el texto nuevo si nos interesa, no?

Comment: ¡Claro! Simplemente debemos recordar ir mirando el original para añadir lo que allí vayan metiendo. De la misma manera, nuestra versión también puede ser un _fork_ e ir metiendo cosas que nos parezcan importantes a nosotros.

Comment: @fedorqui bien (no estaba seguro de que había entendido tu primer comentario)

Answer (score 1):

[estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado)

https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question

**¿Qué hacer en lugar de borrar mi pregunta?**

---

traducción propuesta:

## He pensado mejor sobre mi pregunta ¿puedo borrarla?

Es posible que hayas tenido dudas acerca de algo que has publicado. Tal vez no quieras que tus compañeros de trabajo vean esa pregunta muy específica sobre la búsqueda de empleo, o te das cuenta de que no deberías haber publicado ese código propietario, o no quieres que tus amigos vean ese error estúpido en tu pregunta. **Si nadie ha respondido todavía, sigue adelante y [elimínala](/help/deleted-questions) — a nadie le importa.**

Sin embargo, si tu pregunta tiene buenas respuestas, no es justo que se eliminen esas respuestas junto con tu pregunta: otros usuarios hacen un esfuerzo para ayudarte e incluso si *tú* ya no quieres las respuestas, puede que alguien sí que quiera. Por esta razón, el sistema impide eliminar preguntas respondidas en la mayoría de casos.

Pero hay otras cosas que puedes hacer:

- Si tu pregunta es innecesariamente específica, **edítala** para generalizarla. ¿Realmente necesitas nombrar a empleadores, proveedores u otros detalles específicos? ¿Es tu ubicación realmente importante? ¿Puedes hacer que el código sea más genérico y renombrar algunas variables? No invalides las respuestas existentes y no lo hagas tan vago como para no tener respuesta, pero si pudieras ser una de las miles de personas que podrían haber formulado esa pregunta, es probable que la gente no sepa que fuiste tú. **En casi todos los casos, una edición debería ser todo lo que necesitas.**
- Si realmente no puedes ver una forma de salvar la pregunta al eliminar los detalles de identificación, y ninguna de las respuestas tiene demasiada puntuación, y especialmente si la pregunta está cerrada, puedes reportarla para solicitar que los moderadores la eliminen. Si no hay mucho en juego, podrían hacer eso por ti.
- Si has publicado algo supersensible como una contraseña o una clave de API, edítalo y luego repórtala para pedir a los moderadores que lo **redacten** del historial de revisiones. Sé específico sobre lo que se necesita hacer y (si no es obvio) por qué. Las solicitudes de redacción deben ser aprobadas por dos moderadores, por lo que habrá un retraso. Si la pregunta está cerrada, los moderadores pueden decidir simplemente eliminarla. Consulte [esta publicación](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327145)<sub>en inglés</sub> para obtener una guía más específica sobre cómo preparar una publicación para la redacción sin romperla ni a ella ni a sus respuestas.
- Si la pregunta es buena, no hay nada delicado en ella, y el problema es que *tu nombre está en ella*, es posible que [puedas desvincularla de tu cuenta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96732)<sub>en inglés</sub>. Esto *no* es un verdadero anonimato; Todo lo que publicas en Internet vive para siempre en alguna parte. Las solicitudes son revisadas, lo que lleva tiempo. Si tu solicitud es aprobada, no podrá revertirse más tarde.

Mientras que la redacción y la disociación están permitidas, están destinadas a ser raras excepciones, no acciones rutinarias. Un patrón de publicación precipitada y la solicitud de eliminación, redacción o desasociación, una y otra vez, podría llevar a la suspensión. Publica como si todo lo que escribas sea visible públicamente para siempre.

La vandalización o la eliminación excesiva de publicaciones útiles pueden desencadenar una alerta dentro del sistema y una acción inmediata del equipo de moderación. Sé respetuoso con los esfuerzos de otros: evita invalidar su trabajo o crear una molestia.

**El sistema no puede utilizar nada de esto para levantar un bloqueo de publicación** - si se te impide publicar nuevas preguntas o respuestas, consulta [¿Por qué ya no se aceptan preguntas de mi cuenta?](/help/question-bans) y [¿Por qué ya no se aceptan las respuestas de mi cuenta?](/help/answer-bans) para obtener orientación sobre cómo levantar el bloqueo.

---

texto original (cortesía de g3rv4 en https://github.com/g3rv4/help-pages/blob/master/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question.md, nótese que tiene todo el *markdown* incorporado)

## I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?

You might have had second thoughts about something you've posted. Maybe you don't want your coworkers to see that very specific question about job-hunting, or you realize you shouldn't have posted that proprietary code, or you don't want your friends to see that stupid mistake in your question. **If nobody has answered yet, go ahead and [delete it](/help/deleted-questions) — nobody minds.**

If your question has good answers, though, it's not fair to have those answers removed along with your question: other users put effort into helping you and even if *you* no longer want the answers, somebody else might. This is why the system prevents you from deleting answered questions most of the time.

But there are some other things you can do:

- If your question is unnecessarily specific, **edit** to generalize it. Do you really need to name specific employers, vendors, or other details? Is your location actually important? Can you make the code more generic and rename some variables? Don't invalidate existing answers and don't make it so vague as to be unanswerable, but if you could be one of thousands of people who could have asked that question, people probably won't know it's you. **In almost all cases, an edit should be all you need.**
- If you really can't see a way to salvage the question while removing identifying details, and none of the answers are highly upvoted, and especially if the question is closed, you can use a flag to request that moderators delete it. If there's not much at stake, they might do that for you.
- If you have posted something super-sensitive like a password or an API key, edit it out and then use a flag to ask moderators to **redact** it from the revision history. Be specific about what needs to go and (if it's not obvious) why. Redaction requests must be approved by two moderators, so there will be a delay. If the question is closed, moderators might decide to just delete it instead. See [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327145) for some more specific guidance on preparing a post for redaction without breaking it or its answers.
- If the question is good, there's nothing sensitive in it, and the problem is just that *your name is on it*, you might be able to [have it disassociated from your account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96732). This is *not* true anonymity; anything you post on the Internet lives forever somewhere.  Requests are reviewed, which takes time. If your request is approved, it cannot be reversed later.

While redaction and disassociation are permitted, they are meant to be rare exceptions, not routine actions. A pattern of posting rashly and requesting deletion, redaction, or disassociation, over and over again, could lead to suspension. Post as if everything you write will be publicly visible forever.

Vandalizing or excessive deletion of useful posts may trigger an alert within the system, and prompt action from the moderation team. Please be respectful of the efforts of others: avoid invalidating their work or creating a nuisance.

**None of this can be used to lift a posting block by the system** — if you are blocked from posting new questions or answers, please refer to [Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?](/help/question-bans) and [Why are answers no longer being accepted from my account?](/help/answer-bans) for guidance on how to lift the block.

Comment: Pegale una leida fedorqui a ver si estamos de acuerdo ;)

Comment: @gbianchi gran trabajo! Incluso detecté alguna tilde :P

Comment: <3 es google translate y despues una repasada linea por linea.. aunque no lo creas hace un muy buen trabajo...

Comment: @gbianchi pull request lanzada: https://github.com/g3rv4/help-pages/pull/28

Answer (score 0):

[¿Quiénes son los moderadores del sitio, y cuál es su cometido?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators)

---

En Stack Exchange creemos que la moderación empieza en la propia comunidad, por lo que además del hecho de que los usuarios obtienen [privilegios](/help/privileges) a medida que ganan reputación, cada sitio tiene moderadores que son elegidos mediante voto popular. Regularmente convocamos elecciones para determinar quiénes van a ser estos moderadores (excepto en el caso de los sitios que se encuentran en beta, que tienen [moderadores *pro tempore*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/), designados por el personal de Stack Exchange). Los moderadores son elegidos de por vida, si bien pueden renunciar (o, en casos muy raros, ser destituidos).

Por lo general esperamos que los moderadores:

- sean pacientes y justos
- prediquen con el ejemplo
- muestren respeto por sus compañeros miembros de la comunidad en sus acciones y en sus palabras
- estén dispuestos a ejercer un poco de moderación ligera pero firme, a fin de mantener la comunidad en la buena dirección y resolver disputas (con suerte) poco comunes y excepciones

Además de eso, todos los moderadores deben aceptar y cumplir nuestro [acuerdo del moderador](/legal/moderator-agreement).

#### Los moderadores son controladores de excepciones humanos, están ahí para hacer frente a ciertas condiciones excepcionales que de otra forma podrían comprometer el buen funcionamiento de la comunidad.

La tarea de moderación más común es realizar un seguimiento de las publicaciones reportadas. Todas las publicaciones tienen un pequeño enlace para enviar un reporte, que cualquiera con 15 puntos de reputación puede usar. Las publicaciones pueden reportarse como spam, ofensivas, o simplemente con un “necesita la atención de un moderador” genérico acompañado de un comentario explicativo o un enlace. Las publicaciones reportadas incrementan el contador de reportes que se muestra en la barra superior para cada moderador

Si ves algo en el sistema que es dañino, extraño, o que en algún modo es excepcional y merece la atención de un moderador por cualquier razón…¡[repórtalo](/help/flagging)! Esta es la tarea principal de un moderador: echarle un ojo a cada publicación reportada, y emprender las acciones necesarias.

Los moderadores también tienen algunas capacidades especiales, necesarias para gestionar estas condiciones excepcionales:

- Los votos de los moderadores son vinculantes. En cualquier sitio en el que se puede votar — cerrar, reabrir, borrar, desborrar, contenido ofensivo, migración, etc — el umbral se alcanzará y la acción correspondiente se realizará inmediatamente si un solo moderador emite un voto.
- Los moderadores pueden bloquear publicaciones. Las publicaciones bloqueadas no pueden ser votadas ni cambiadas de ninguna manera.
- Los moderadores pueden [proteger preguntas](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/07/new-protected-question-status/). Las preguntas protegidas sólo admiten respuestas de usuarios con más de 10 puntos de reputación.
- Los moderadores pueden ver más datos en el sistema, incluyendo estadísticas de voto (pero no ‘quién ha votado en esta publicación’) e información de perfil de usuario.
- Los moderadores pueden poner usuarios en [suspensión temporal](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/), y borrar usuarios si es necesario.
- Los moderadores pueden realizar tareas de mantenimiento a gran escala como combinar respuestas y etiquetas, aprobar sinónimos de etiqueta, etc.

Gran parte del trabajo de moderación es bastante mundano: borrar spam obvio, cerrar preguntas descaradamente fuera de tema, y sacrificar algunas de las publicaciones peor valoradas en el sitio. El moderador ideal hace lo mínimo posible, pero sus acciones son poderosas, visibles, y altamente concentradas.

Si tienes preguntas acerca de las razones tras las acciones de un moderador, inicia una discusión en meta. Recuerda: sé **constructivo y educado**; los moderadores quieren lo mejor para el sitio, pero ocasionalmente pueden cometer errores o tener que hacer frente a cuestiones controvertidas en las que no todo el mundo está de acuerdo.

Por favor, lee [Una teoría de la moderación](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation) para más información sobre nuestra filosofía de moderación

#### Los moderadores actúan como una conexión entre la comunidad y Stack Exchange como empresa.

Los moderadores del sitio también pueden elevar problemas de moderación contactando con el equipo de Stack Exchange para solicitar consejo, o por cuestiones administrativas o técnicas.

Adicionalmente, los moderadores pueden ayudar a atraer atención extra sobre fallos, peticiones de características, y otras cuestiones que afectan al sitio si la comunidad no es capaz de resolver la cuestión en el sitio meta.

Los moderadores del sitio se distinguen de los usuarios normales porque se muestra un diamante (♦) junto a sus nombres de usuario. Algunos empleados de Stack Exchange también
tienen diamantes junto a sus nombres de usuario; normalmente estos son desarrolladores o community managers, u otros empleados que trabajan directamente con nuestros usuarios para resolver fallos o resolver otras preocupaciones de la comunidad. Los empleados de Stack Exchange se identifican como tales en sus perfiles de usuario.

Averigua quiénes son los [moderadores de este sitio](/users?tab=moderators), o explora la lista de [los moderadores en todos los sitios de Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/about/moderators).