# Obteniendo respuestas

Tags: discusión, preguntas

¿Cuáles son las recomendaciones para escribir preguntas buenas y útiles que obtengan las mejores respuestas posibles?

> La idea de esta publicación es servir como enlace en la página [¿Por qué ya no se aceptan preguntas desde mi cuenta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) del Centro de Ayuda, que actualmente apunta a [*Getting Answers*](https://www.mikeash.com/getting_answers.html) de Mike Ash. Voy a incluir ese enlace como respuesta, y una traducción mínima.
>
> La idea es que sirva como una guía generada por la comunidad, con contenido bien trabajado entre todos. Los invito a editar mi respuesta o a contribuir nuevas respuestas (siempre y cuando tengan un contenido exhaustivo y de buena calidad).

Comment: Me parece una buena idea. Pero no te parece que sería interesante pedir permiso al autor para reproducir aqui ese contenido?

Comment: @Pikoh lo tuve en cuenta. Tomé como válida la respuesta de Mike Ash a un comentario que preguntaba si se podía traducir, al que respondió: "*that’s no problem at all! Proper attribution is all I ask. Translations are most welcome. Thanks for asking in any case*"([fuente](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/getting-answers.html#comment-e57e9e83660506446c0a9e7baf2807a9)).

Comment: no esperaba menos de ti, pero por si se te había escapado ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Esta guía (*en inglés*) contiene excelentes recomendaciones de cómo escribir preguntas que obtengan respuestas. Les recomiendo leerla.

## [Getting Answers](https://www.mikeash.com/getting_answers.html#guide_begin)

Autor: Mike Ash

---

> Estos son los puntos principales, traducidos de forma muy resumida (y bastante adaptada).

#### 1. Explica lo que no funciona

Aunque parezca obvio, no lo es. Muchos pueden preguntarte sobre cuestiones de tu técnica o sobre algo relacionado que crean que es más simple, en vez de simplemente decirte qué está mal. Si crees que es un problema con la técnica en general, pregunta eso también.

Especifica desde el principio exactamente qué es lo que está mal.

#### 2. Proporciona todo por adelantado

Hacer que la gente tenga que ir de pesca para obtener toda la información es una pérdida de tiempo. Provee toda la información relacionada que sea posible en tu pregunta.

Resumir tu pregunta no te va a ahorrar tiempo (eventualmente vas a terminar agregándolo de todas formas), y hace que quienes pudieran ayudarte estén menos predispuestos a responderte, tanto en tu pregunta actual como en futuras. Quizás te preocupe estar diciendo demasiado. ¡No lo estés! Es muchísimo mejor excederse en detalles específicos que ser poco específico, ya que es mucho más sencillo para cualquiera ignorar los detalles extras que tener que preguntarte por la información que falta. Ante la duda, agrega algo como: "*No estoy muy seguro de si es relevante, pero estoy haciendo...*".

#### 3. Publica tu código

Esto es esencial. Nunca describas las generalidades de tu enfoque al problema sin antes publicar el código que aplica a tu problema. El código es lo que importa, y traducir todo en palabras tiende a alterarlo significativamente.

Preguntar por el código lleva tiempo y esfuerzo, y se puede acelerar una respuesta si se proporciona desde el principio. Si no sabes si es o no relevante, publícalo de todas formas.

#### 4. Investiga antes

Aunque puede ser una buena idea buscar una solución rápida apenas surge, preguntarle a desconocidos debería ser un último recurso. Intenta investigar todo lo que puedas, buscando resolverlo por tu cuenta antes de preguntar.

Esto te va a ayudar a obtener respuestas, permitiéndote formular preguntas mucho más informadas. Cuanto más sepas sobre el tema, será más probable que estés preguntando exactamente lo que necesitas.

Si explicas lo que ya investigaste, evitas que te envíen a leer la documentación.

#### 5. Investiga durante

Tu trabajo no termina al preguntar. Cuando te ofrezcan alguna recomendación que no conozcas, investiga antes de repreguntar. Incluso algo tan sencillo como googlear algún término que no conozcas puede ayudar muchísimo.

Investigar no sólo tu pregunta original sino también las preguntas que te surjan como consecuencia de las recomendaciones hará que obtengas respuestas mucho más útiles.

#### 6. Investiga después

Una vez que obtengas posibles soluciones, también deberías investigar todo lo que puedas antes de volver y hacer nuevas preguntas relacionadas.

Al igual que antes, investigar hace que obtengas mejores respuestas.

#### 7. No vuelvas a publicar la misma pregunta

A menos que tu problema sea especialmente intrincado, muchos pueden ayudarte. Lo más probable es que alguno haya visto tu primera pregunta. No vuelvas a hacer la misma pregunta.

Si no obtuviste respuestas, investiga aún más, intenta generar un ejemplo mínimo que reproduzca completamente el problema, o al menos intenta reducir un poco tu problema. Vuelve en uno o dos días con más información.

Si nadie pudo responderte, probablemente quieran aún menos responderte a una segunda pregunta repetida. Utiliza el tiempo en el que estás esperando una respuesta para trabajar en el problema por tu cuenta. Incluso sin la más remota esperanza de solucionarlo, se puede recolectar información que ayude a que otros lo solucionen.

#### 8. Haz el seguimiento luego de obtener una respuesta

Siempre deberías responderle a quienes te dan consejos, incluso cuando está entendido y funciona perfectamente, tanto que no necesitas más información.

Quienes responden lo hacen gratuitamente. Como a un cachorro sentado esperando una orden, necesitas elogiarlo y retribuirle cuando hace lo que quieres.

> CP: En el sitio puede ser suficiente el aceptar una respuesta. Los comentarios de agradecimiento o mencionando que funcionó son considerados innecesarios.

En preguntas complejas, sigue el tema describiendo cómo es que finalmente lo solucionaste y cuál de los consejos seguiste. Esto no solo provee un reconocimiento, sino que también permite que otros aprendan de tu caso.

#### 9. Trata a la comunidad como personas

Muchos comentarios pueden llegar a dar la impresión sutil e indirecta de que la comunidad es una especie de máquina de respuestas, y de que la clave para obtener una buena respuesta está en seguir demandando hasta encontrar la solución en el formato requerido por la pregunta.

No es un juego, estás hablando con personas de carne y hueso. Trátalos como personas a las que les estás hablando cara a cara y obtendrás un mejor resultado.

#### 10. Siempre considera la respuesta

A veces un verdadero idiota te va a responder, y a veces obtendrás la respuesta de alguien muy inteligente que está teniendo un mal día o que no leyó correctamente tu pregunta. Sin embargo, generalmente vas a estar interactuando con personas que conocen mucho más del tema que lo que sabes (por eso es que preguntaste en este lugar en primera instancia, no te lo olvides). Como tal, vale la pena al menos considerar la posibilidad de que sepan de lo que están hablando.

Si la respuesta en realidad era correcta, vas a ganar muchísimo tiempo si empiezas asumiendo que lo era. Si asumes que está equivocada, o vas a tener que esperar a que te corrijan, o ni siquiera se va a preocupar por corregirte y vas a quedarte sin respuesta. Incluso si la respuesta está mal, son mayores las probabilidades de obtener una respuesta correcta si eres amable al señalar lo incorrecto.

Comment: ¿También utilizáis _chances_ en Argentina? :O

Comment: @fedorqui tan frecuentemente que ni siquiera me percaté de que es termino acuñado, -¡y eso que intenté evitar localismos! Hice un esfuerzo en no poner las tildes donde van para mí. Modificalo con la expresión que te parezca mejor, esa es la idea.

Comment: Jejeje en España no se usa más que por influencia de gente venida de Hispanoamérica. Pero viendo el [DAMER](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=chance) parece que somos los únicos en no usarlo y el [DLE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8XX5qml) ya lo recoge. Mañana miro si se me ocurre algo, ¡gracias por la _currada_! (¡ostras! que [veo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Bk15xpi) que significa estafar en Argentina...)

Comment: Se podría cambiar *chances* perfectamente por *probabilidades* en los dos sitios en que aparece en el texto. Aunque no sé si es necesario, por el contexto creo que la mayoría lo entenderá.

Comment: Propongo _oportunidades_ como sinónimo de _chances_, aunque probabilidades también me parece correcto

Comment: Siéntanse en total libertad de editar todo lo que quieran.. si prefieren que la haga wiki, márquenla wiki, o si no se animan, avisen y lo hago... Mi traducción fue bastante rápida y sin prestar atención en los detalles. Prefería tener lo primero que me saliera para poder modificar el enlace del Centro de Ayuda a español.