# Mejora de artículo de ayuda Reportar publicaciones (privileges/flag-posts)

Tags: discusión, traducciones, centro-de-ayuda

El artículo de ayuda [Reportar publicaciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) ya está traducido pero tiene algunas cosas que ser mejorado. Ya envié un PR en https://github.com/g3rv4/help-pages/ con algunas mejoras.

Punto y aparte de lo anterior, en este artículo de ayuda, los siguientes enlaces apuntan a respuestas en Meta SE. Seguramente sería muy útil tenerlos traducidos acá.

- [Guía de uso para *spam* y *grosero/abusivo*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035) (respuesta a [faq](/questions/tagged/faq), se incluye en ...¡Traduce un FAQ!)
- [Guía de uso para *no es una respuesta*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81392) (respuesta a duplicado)
- [Guía de reporte *fuera de tema*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169824) (respuesta a discusión)
- [Guía de uso para *muy baja calidad*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93606) (respuesta a característica nueva)
- [Guía para comentar reportes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17365) (respuesta a [faq](/questions/tagged/faq), se incluye en ...¡Traduce un FAQ!)

Si alguien se anima a traducir alguna de las guías anteriores responda indicando el enlace a la traducción.

Relacionado

- [¿Sabes inglés, quieres aportar a la comunidad de SOes y no sabes cómo? ¡Traduce un FAQ!](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1380/65)

Comment: estimado! no es necesario que publiques la pregunta para generar la url de la imagen... con que la inicies y subas la imagen podés usar la URL

Comment: @g3rv4 No creo que haga daño alguno el publicarlo, además nunca sé cuando me van a interrumpir, o se reinicie mi laptop inesperadamente (es HP Pavilion con Windows) :)

Comment: genial, yo porque no me quedaba claro el objetivo de la pregunta y me pareció que era para generar la url

Comment: Esa fue la intención inicial... hasta que me interrumpieron, jeje. Luego me dí cuenta que los enlaces a las guías apuntan a Meta SE...

Comment: Yo tampoco entiendo el sentido de esta publicación.

Comment: @fedorqui ajuste un poco la redacción. A ver si ahora sirve para algo :)

Comment: interesante... pues lo mismo se podría renombrar la pregunta a un simple ¿quién se anima a traducir estos artículos? Poniendo una respuesta con cada uno, con el inglés original y espacio para que cada cual ponga en castellano. O incluso simplemente añadirlas en [¿Sabes inglés, quieres aportar a la comunidad de SOes y no sabes cómo? ¡Traduce un FAQ!](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1380/83), tu muy buena idea que tenemos algo olvidada últimamente.

Comment: @fedorqui Cambiar el título podría ayudar a hacerla mas clara, de acuerdo. En cuando a añadirlas a ...¡Traduce un FAQ! sólo un par de las guías son [meta-tag:faq], tal vez esas se incluyen ahí e inclusive podrían estar traducidas ya (: Las otras podrían incluirse y quizas esta marcarse como duplicado de aquella, sería cosa de "revivir" aquel hilo y hacer los ajustes que hiciesen falta, sólo me intriga un poco como sería mejor hacer el seguimiento para coordinar la actualización de los enlaces en el artículo de ayuda al que se refiere esta pregunta.

Comment: _sólo me intriga un poco como sería mejor hacer el seguimiento para coordinar la actualización de los enlaces en el artículo de ayuda al que se refiere esta pregunta_ precisamente eso estoy meditando, como viste en GitHub. La pregunta [Traduzcamos las páginas y enlaces del “Centro de Ayuda” y de “Privilegios”](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3264/83) quedó pequeña, por lo que no sé exactamente cómo obrar. Tengo pendiente plantearlo en Meta, como comenté a @g3rv4. ¿Y si en este caso específico tuviéramos una pregunta con respuesta wiki con todo el listado de enlaces por traducir?

Comment: Por caso específico ¿te refieres a poner una respuesta wiki por cada artículo de ayuda con los enlaces pendiente de traducir? Supongo que podemos hacer eso en un hilo similar a [Sabes inglés...](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1380/83)

Comment: Pero en lo personal pienso que debemos tener un hilo por artículo de ayuda que requiera arreglo. Así podemos sacar mejor provecho de [meta-tag:estado-completado] y la etiqueta [meta-tag:centro-de-ayuda] o una similar Recuerda que ahora podemos tener etiquetas más largas que lo que se permitía originalmente.

Answer (score 0):

Propuesta de destino de [Guía de reporte de uso para *muy baja calidad*]

[¿Cómo debo de usar el reporte [muy baja calidad] (en inglés VLQ)?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3464/65)