# Falta traduccion para pagina del help que hacer en lugar de borrar mi pregunta

Tags: discusión, traducciones

No encuentro por ningun lado en [traducir](http://traducir.win) como traducir la pagina del help https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question

Los mods tienen acceso a la misma o necesitamos a nicolas para que nos ayude a traducirla?

Comment: Creo, pero no estoy seguro, que se debe hacer un PR al proyecto de g3rv4 [aquí](https://github.com/g3rv4/help-pages). Se habla algo al respecto aquí: [Traduzcamos las páginas y enlaces del “Centro de Ayuda” y de “Privilegios”](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3264/22721)

Comment: cuando tenes razon.. tenes razon.. vamos para alla entonces...

Comment: parece una nueva página, no me suena haberla visto antes.

Comment: yo tampoco la habia visto @fedorqui.. es mas.. nunca hablamos de ella... es logico que no este traducida..

Comment: Sos un groso @KacosPro ;)

Comment: [Acá](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318782/289691) estoy preguntando si hay forma de enterarnos de artículos de ayuda que deban ser traducidos.

Comment: No es tan nueva, hace tiempo que lo comenté en el chat y haces unos día volvía a comentarlo a ver si alguien se animaba a traducirla. Por otra parte, aunque es otro tema, en esa  misma sección de ayuda deberíamos eliminar esta página, no?: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask-beta

Comment: Añadí el markdown en [una respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3747/83) por si la queremos traducir entre todos.